# Stuck in asp.net core tutorial. Trying to use package manager console to add EF Core SQL Server provider does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am following [this beginners tutorial on Microsoft's site.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

At this step...

```
In the PMC, run the following command:
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

When I enter that command I get these messages and errors..

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Restoring packages for C:\projects\LazerbaseASPNET\LazerbaseASPNET\LazerbaseASPNET.csproj...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver/index.json 208ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver/6.0.7/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver.6.0.7.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver/6.0.7/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver.6.0.7.nupkg 71ms
Installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.7 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash D9YV3hc3VSN1qrfdrZcKtMcRLT6bUqj8KtaUdkmO1CH/+meL+8z3Rge5iPhwQ4ol2AwPQlQYVPTTajf9ulSFGg==.
Install-Package : NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.7 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.7 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 
Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'LazerbaseASPNET'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 
Time Elapsed: 00:00:03.2286177
```

Seems the important one is this...

```
Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.7 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.7 supports: net6.0
```

This tutorial is *for* asp.net core 3.1.. It seems to be the one they recommend for beginners also. I am at a impass and have no idea how to proceed.

EDIT:
I think this is cus I used Visual Studio 2019 which I already had installed for Unity.. asp.net core 3.1 was the only option available for a new project... I think I need to wipe the existing server from azure, download Visual Studio 2022 and start again with a asp.net core 6 app ?

Comment: Try installing the [v3.1.x version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/3.1.27) of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer as they are versioned after the version of .NET (Core). i.e. Version 6.0.7 will only be for .NET 6

Comment: You’ll have to use a newer .NET or install an older package version that still supports 3.1

Comment: Or, as @SamiKuhmonen says, update your project to .NET 6

Comment: There's no reason to still use the netcore3.1, assuming the tutorial doesn't cover any advanced stuff, you should try to follow it but on .net6.

Comment: I think this is cus I used VS 2019 which I already had installed for Unity.. asp.net core 3.1 was the only option available for a new project... I think I need to wipe the existing server from azure, download VS 2022 and start again with a asp.net core 6 app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is cus I used Visual Studio 2019 which I already had installed for Unity.. asp.net core 3.1 was the only option available for a new project.
The solution is wipe the existing server from azure, download Visual Studio 2022 and start again with a asp.net core 6 app.
FML.

I also want to point out that this tutorial is wrong. [Earlier in it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) it says requirement is Visual Studio 2019 16.4 or later.

[image]

I did read this and checked the version of Visual studio I had installed, I met the requirements so I kept going.

Comment: It's fine, as long as you install a suitable version of entity framework, as i described earlyer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to install entity framework core through the nuget package manager.
Rightclick on your project -> Manage Nuget packages. Before installing select the correct version from the dropdown for the netcore app version you are running.

Comment: I think this is cus I used VS 2019 which I already had installed for Unity.. asp.net core 3.1 was the only option available for a new project... I think I need to wipe the existing server from azure, download VS 2022 and start again with a asp.net core 6 app ?

Comment: Since its a tutorial I would recommend to do as you describe. If it was a production application this is a different situation.